# Non proxy hosts for OkHttp3

Tags: java, http-proxy, okhttp

How can I set what hostnames should not pass in one request made by `OkHttpClient` using a proxy?

Is there anything equivalent for the vm argument `-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts` in OkHttp3?

For example:

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient
    .Builder()
    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,
        new InetSocketAddress(defaultProxyHostName, Integer.parseInt(defaultProxyPort))))
    .build();
```

Comment: If you'd prefer to use an environment variable, in my experience OkHttp seems to respect `no_proxy` / `NO_PROXY`. E.g. you can `export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1` before you run the VM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging around a bit, I have found out how to do it.

So I had to create a [`ProxySelector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html) implementing the logic when the proxy should be applied or not.

### Example:

```
final ProxySelector proxySelector = new ProxySelector() {
    @Override
    public java.util.List<Proxy> select(final URI uri) {
        final List<Proxy> proxyList = new ArrayList<Proxy>(1);

        // Host
        final String host = uri.getHost();

        // Is an internal host
        if (host.startsWith("127.0.0.1") || StringUtils.contains(nonProxyHostsValue, host)) {
            proxyList.add(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
        } else {
            // Add proxy
            proxyList.add(new Proxy(Type.HTTP,
                    new InetSocketAddress(proxyHostNameValue, Integer.parseInt(proxyPortValue))));
        }

        return proxyList;
    }

    @Override
    public void connectFailed(URI arg0, SocketAddress arg1, IOException arg2) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
};

// Set proxy selector
okHttpClientBuilder.proxySelector(proxySelector);
```

Comment: Could you please add imports to the code, please? The StringUtils.contains is vague and I'm not sure where it is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

The API you're looking for is [ProxySelector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html). You can configure this on your OkHttpClient.

Comment: I saw this class, but i did not realize how to do it. Can you share any code or sample demonstrating this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to pass argument

```
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|*.example.com
```